# Why is the file size of the executable file larger than the .cpp source file with no includes?

Tags: c++, windows, g++, cygwin

Why is the file size of the executable file larger than the source? I made the example below (the simplest one I could think of) and it the executable is still so huge compared to the source, even though (I think) it's not using any libraries.

Simplest.cpp: 33 bytes

Simplest.s:   386 bytes

Simplest.exe: 60076 bytes

Simplest.cpp:

```
int main(void)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Simplest.s:

```
        .file   "Simplest.cpp"
        .def    ___main;        .scl    2;      .type   32;     .endef
        .text
        .globl  _main
        .def    _main;  .scl    2;      .type   32;     .endef
_main:
LFB0:
        .cfi_startproc
        pushl   %ebp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
        .cfi_offset 5, -8
        movl    %esp, %ebp
        .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
        andl    $-16, %esp
        call    ___main
        movl    $0, %eax
        leave
        .cfi_restore 5
        .cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
LFE0:
        .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 4.8.3"
```

Not sure if it's relevant, but I'm using g++ compiler on cygwin on Windows 8 with an Intel processor.

Comment: _Not sure if it's relevant, but I'm using g++ compiler on cygwin on Windows 8 with an Intel processor._ <-- all of these are _absolutely_ relevant.

Comment: You can run `objdump -s -d Simplest.exe` to see what went into the final executable.  But I'm not sure if that tool is available for your platform.

Comment: @5gon12eder Thanks, I tried it and was able to see that a lot of other things were included in the executable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The executable is linked with lots of libraries. So, when your compiler's done linking, the file size increases. `libc` or `libc++` are always linked against when you're building a C or C++ program.

You could read this [article](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/10/gcc-linking/) about *gcc*'s linking process.

[`ld`'s manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ld) says

> **ld** combines a number of object and archive files, relocates their data and ties up symbol references. Usually the last step in compiling a program is to run **ld**.

All in all, linkers may put lots of stuff into the executable. No wonder why its size can be greater than the source file's size.

---

Note: the links above are about linking on Unix, not Windows, but Cygwin tries to somehow simulate the behavior of Linux/Unix systems, so they're still relevant.

Comment: You should explain what libraries are linked, when none are explicitly requested.

Comment: Thanks for telling exactly which libraries are linked

Answer (score 2):

ForceBru has explained what's going on at a high level, but it seems that you already understand that linking libraries could increase executable size, but (mistakenly) believe that your program uses no libraries.

Actually, because you linked your program by running `gcc`, when `ld` was invoked, `gcc` passed some extra options.  To control this, read about [`gcc` Link Options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html)

Of particular interest are the `-nostdlib` and `-nodefaultlibs` options, described as follows:

> ## `-nodefaultlibs`
>
> Do not use the standard system libraries when linking. Only the libraries you specify are passed to the linker, and options specifying linkage of the system libraries, such as `-static-libgcc` or `-shared-libgcc`, are ignored. The standard startup files are used normally, unless `-nostartfiles` is used.
>
> The compiler may generate calls to `memcmp`, `memset`, `memcpy` and `memmove`. These entries are usually resolved by entries in `libc`. These entry points should be supplied through some other mechanism when this option is specified.
>
> ## `-nostdlib`
>
> Do not use the standard system startup files or libraries when linking. No startup files and only the libraries you specify are passed to the linker, and options specifying linkage of the system libraries, such as `-static-libgcc` or `-shared-libgcc`, are ignored.
>
> The compiler may generate calls to `memcmp`, `memset`, `memcpy` and `memmove`. These entries are usually resolved by entries in `libc`. These entry points should be supplied through some other mechanism when this option is specified.
>
> One of the standard libraries bypassed by `-nostdlib` and `-nodefaultlibs` is `libgcc.a`, a library of internal subroutines which GCC uses to overcome shortcomings of particular machines, or special needs for some languages. (See Interfacing to GCC Output, for more discussion of `libgcc.a`.) In most cases, you need `libgcc.a` even when you want to avoid other standard libraries. In other words, when you specify `-nostdlib` or `-nodefaultlibs` you should usually specify `-lgcc` as well. This ensures that you have no unresolved references to internal GCC library subroutines. (An example of such an internal subroutine is `__main`, used to ensure C++ constructors are called; see `collect2`.)

Because you haven't used these options, your code *is* in fact being linked with multiple libraries.

To understand some of the behavior provided by those libraries, without which even your tiny program will fail, you might read the blog series [Hello from a libc-free world!](https://blogs.oracle.com/ksplice/entry/hello_from_a_libc_free) ([Part 2](https://blogs.oracle.com/ksplice/entry/hello_from_a_libc_free1))

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the link! You are exactly right, I misunderstood that my program does in fact use libraries.